# Objective-C: -[NSString wordCount]

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, word-count

What's a simple implementation of the following `NSString` category method that returns the number of words in `self`, where words are separated by any number of consecutive spaces or newline characters? Also, the string will be less than 140 characters, so in this case, I prefer simplicity & readability at the sacrifice of a bit of performance.

```
@interface NSString (Additions)
- (NSUInteger)wordCount;
@end
```

I found the following solutions:

- [implementation of -[NSString wordCount]](http://macdevnotes.com/nsstring-word-count)
- [implementation of -[NSString wordCount]](http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSString) - seems a bit simpler

But, isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to do better than a linear search here. Depending on the implementation of scanUpToCharactersFromSet, this might fare better than O(n) in most cases.

Comment: @tjarratt: I think the OP wants the "simplest" method, not necessarily the fastest.

Comment: How about enumerating by word and and counting by using NSStringEnumerationByWords in a string enumeration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count words within a text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266434/how-to-count-words-within-a-text-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the second link I gave in my question still reigns as not only the fastest but also, in hindsight, a relatively simple [implementation of -[NSString wordCount]](http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSString).

Comment: Definition of a word is not customisable with this implementation.

Answer (score 16):

Why not just do the following?

```
- (NSUInteger)wordCount {
    NSCharacterSet *separators = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    NSArray *words = [self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separators];

    NSIndexSet *separatorIndexes = [words indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [obj isEqualToString:@""];
    }];

    return [words count] - [separatorIndexes count];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems exactly correct & simple. I wonder if it's efficient. Good enough in my case though as I'm building an iOS app, not an operating system. :) I like it!

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think this is exactly correct. According to the Xcode documentation: "Adjacent occurrences of the separator characters produce empty strings in the result. Similarly, if the string begins or ends with separator characters, the first or last substring, respectively, is empty." I do not want to count empty strings as words. E.g., the method should return 1 for `@" hello "`, not 3.

Comment: nice! It works! I also confirmed the correctness another solution I found on the net, and it seems about twice as fast as your implementation and still fairly simple. So, [I posted it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171422/objective-c-nsstring-wordcount/6171849#6171849).

Answer (score 11):

I believe you have identified the 'simplest'. Nevertheless, to answer to your original question - "a simple implementation of the following NSString *category*...", and have it posted directly here for posterity:

```
@implementation NSString (GSBString)

- (NSUInteger)wordCount
{
    __block int words = 0;
    [self enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0,self.length)
                             options:NSStringEnumerationByWords
                          usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {words++;}];
    return words;
}

@end
```

Comment: Definition of a word is not customisable with this implementation.

Comment: @Cœur but there is languages without spaces.

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of simpler implementations, but they all have tradeoffs. For example, Cocoa (but not Cocoa Touch) has word-counting baked in:

```
- (NSUInteger)wordCount {
    return [[NSSpellChecker sharedSpellChecker] countWordsInString:self language:nil];
}
```

It's also trivial to count words as accurately as the scanner simply using `[[self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] count]`. But I've found the performance of that method degrades a lot for longer strings.

So it depends on the tradeoffs you want to make. I've found the absolute fastest is just to go straight-up [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/). If you want simplest, using existing code is probably simpler than writing any code at all.

Answer (score 4):

```
- (NSUInteger) wordCount
{
   NSArray *words = [self componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
   return [words count];
}
```

Comment: This over counts if you have runs of spaces or newlines.

Comment: Wrong count for multiple spaces or multiple newlines `@"\n\n\n"`. Please see above correct solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6171439/1033581

Answer (score 1):

A Objective-C one-liner version

```
NSInteger wordCount = word ? ([word stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet.invertedSet].length + 1) : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
let words: [Any] = (string.components(separatedBy: " "))
let count = words.count
```